# I can't find app.js file in sails.js in v0.10.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am working with sails.js **framework version 0.10**, I am playing around with socket.io. The problem is that I cannot find the **app.js** file that is placed in */assets/js* in older sails.js versions.

I am wondering where can I find this file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need /assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js. Take a look [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js.html).